# Options for optimizing a table with millions of rows and lots of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm about to insert millions of rows into a database. Is having one table with lots of columns more or less practical than having multiple tables with lots of rows?

The data sort of looks like this:

```
  user   Jan01   Jan02   Jan03  ...
abcdef  459232  958394  319348
ghijkl  583941  813941  438923
mnopqr  681294  249393  934304
...
```

I thought about breaking it up by month but then I would end up with about 60 tables with millions of rows. Breaking it up by year would still make the tables result in ~365 columns each. If I'm going to that extent, I figure I might as well just have one table because then it would save space and completely remove any redundancy (which is always a good in programming).

However, having one table with ~365*~60 columns sounds so crazy.

Is there a feature or something that would solve my problems that I don't know about? What would you do?

Comment: You probably need to normalize this table. What kind of data are you storing? How will it be accessed? The more data you give, the best we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the table long rather than wide.

If you make the table:

```
user | date | data
```

then you queries will be a lot faster.

You also need to make sure you index the columns correctly.

FInally dont use `varchar` etc. if you can avoid it - if you know the length of a column and it will always be an `integer` then make sure it is Type: `integer Length 11` (or whatever) as this will massively speed up queries.

**EDIT**

to make this easier to understand your table should be

```
user       | date       | data

abcdef      Jan01         459232
abcdef      Jan02         958394
abcdef      Jan03         319438
ghijkl      Jan01         583941
ghijkl      Jan02         813941
ghijkl      Jan03         438923
mnopqr      Jan01         681294
mnopqr      Jan02         249393
mnopqr      Jan03         934304
```

This allows you to query the data effectively, insert and update data more easily and is how database are designed to be (long not wide).

**even with 6 million rows it will still be faster than a table 60 columns wide with 100,000 rows.**

Comment: I don't exactly get why everyone's saying long and not wide. My question was asking if I should have multiple tables of the same length or have one table of the same length but of a large width.

Comment: and I am saying have a single table that is very long - just three columns `user, date and the data` You dont need multiple tables - just one very long one (think of it like this you have user: data in a table - the third column 'date' is effectively your table name if you had a different table for each date.)

Comment: editted the answer to explain why to do it this way.

Comment: 5,000,000 rows * 365 days * 5 years = 9,125,000,000. That's nine billion rows. Let's say each row is 40 bytes. That would make the table 340 gigabytes. If I sum the days' totals into months (5,000,000 * 12 * 5), that's still 300,000,000, but only 11 gigabytes. I'd like to preserve the daily specifics, but I think the only practical thing to do is use your suggestion and just sum the totals into months.

Comment: I think the biggest problem you will have is getting the data into the database in the first place - at 1000 rows / second (which is about the insert speed on a standard server) you are looking at 105 days! Good luck!

Comment: I did a little test some time ago with one of the files. Executing a PHP script in Chrome on localhost, I used `LOAD DATA INFILE` to insert about 3,000,000 lines and it only took about 10 minutes. I'm lucky to have the data in a somewhat structured format already.

Answer (score 1):

Make one table with lots of rows. Don't break it up by anything.

If it really gets too big, you can [partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll agree with the other two posters -- tables work better "long" than "wide".

Indexes, clustered indexes, bitmaps, temp tables, locking, transaction journalling & all the other years of research & sophisticated algorithms of a database are designed to operate & select in the vertical dimension -- down the rows.

Go wide, and you're throwing away all the machinery that makes a database work and gives it good performance.

Writing 365*60 columns will probably exceed your DB's maximum rowsize limit; but if it didn't, reading/writing/updating anything will require the entirety of every affected or non-excludable row (around 131 KB) to be accessed.  Here are some of the benefits, for your amusement:

- Data-items can no longer be inserted incrementally; you need to write a whole row at once.
- Indexing would largely be inapplicable. Say goodbye to performance.
- SQL & prepared statements degenerate.. now having to be generated specifically for the (month,year) column involved.
- Say goodbye to reporting by user across years, by year across users, etc, in any easy manner ever.
- Any non-trivial queries/ reports now require tables scans over the entire dataset. Millions of rows, you said? Say goodbye to reporting by user across years, by year across users, etc, in any performant way ever.
- If anything's going to break your DB's internal buffers, journal or transaction logs, or the database driver -- this is probably a good to find it :) Get friendly with unexpected technical limitations & unusual failure cases.

So, neither easy nor performant :) But worthwhile to consider, as this helps give an illustration & understanding of what the database actually does.

Hope you found this interesting!